# Saving an entity with EF and dispatching a message to the client with SignalR in the same method

Tags: .net-core, websocket, signalr, ef-core-3.1

I have a problem with **WebSocket being disconnected** while trying to firstly save entity to the database with `EF Core`, then to dispatch a message to the clients using `SignalR Core`.

Everything works perfectly when I separate these two operations, one with AJAX call to the `controller's action`, to save entity to the database, one with `hub method` for dispatching messages to the clients. But I want **to ensure that the entity is successfully saved**, then to be dispatched.

> When I try to **merge** saving entity and dispatching a message to the clients into the same hub method or controller's action (with dependency injection), I've got the errors which could be found down bellow (with log level - trace).

```
00:51:03.876 [2020-01-04T23:51:03.877Z] Trace: (WebSockets transport) sending data. String data of length 307. Utils.ts:178:39
00:51:04.147 [2020-01-04T23:51:04.148Z] Trace: (WebSockets transport) socket closed. Utils.ts:178:39
00:51:04.148 [2020-01-04T23:51:04.148Z] Debug: HttpConnection.stopConnection(undefined) called while in state Connected. Utils.ts:178:39
00:51:04.148 [2020-01-04T23:51:04.149Z] Information: Connection disconnected. Utils.ts:174:39
00:51:04.149 [2020-01-04T23:51:04.149Z] Debug: HubConnection.connectionClosed(undefined) called while in state Connected. Utils.ts:178:39
00:51:04.149 [2020-01-04T23:51:04.149Z] Information: Connection reconnecting. Utils.ts:174:39
00:51:04.150 [2020-01-04T23:51:04.150Z] Information: Reconnect attempt number 1 will start in 0 ms. Utils.ts:174:39

00:51:04.150 Chat - Error: Invocation canceled due to the underlying connection being closed. conversation line 2 > scriptElement:27:36

00:51:04.153 [2020-01-04T23:51:04.153Z] Debug: Starting connection with transfer format 'Text'. Utils.ts:178:39
00:51:04.154 [2020-01-04T23:51:04.154Z] Debug: Sending negotiation request: http://localhost:11597/chatHub/negotiate?negotiateVersion=1. Utils.ts:178:39
00:51:04.168 [2020-01-04T23:51:04.169Z] Debug: Selecting transport 'WebSockets'. Utils.ts:178:39
00:51:04.168 [2020-01-04T23:51:04.169Z] Trace: (WebSockets transport) Connecting. Utils.ts:178:39
00:51:04.179 [2020-01-04T23:51:04.180Z] Information: WebSocket connected to ws://localhost:11597/chatHub?id=Amf9CsFZQfnR8-3PoGr8HQ. Utils.ts:174:39
00:51:04.179 [2020-01-04T23:51:04.180Z] Debug: The HttpConnection connected successfully. Utils.ts:178:39
00:51:04.180 [2020-01-04T23:51:04.180Z] Debug: Sending handshake request. Utils.ts:178:39

00:51:04.180 [2020-01-04T23:51:04.181Z] Debug: Hub handshake failed with error 'WebSocket is not in the OPEN state' during start(). Stopping HubConnection. Utils.ts:178:39

00:51:04.181 [2020-01-04T23:51:04.181Z] Trace: (WebSockets transport) socket closed. Utils.ts:178:39
00:51:04.181 [2020-01-04T23:51:04.182Z] Debug: HttpConnection.stopConnection(undefined) called while in state Disconnecting. Utils.ts:178:39
00:51:04.182 [2020-01-04T23:51:04.182Z] Error: Connection disconnected with error 'WebSocket is not in the OPEN state'. Utils.ts:168:39
00:51:04.183 [2020-01-04T23:51:04.184Z] Debug: HubConnection.connectionClosed(WebSocket is not in the OPEN state) called while in state Reconnecting. Utils.ts:178:39
00:51:04.183 [2020-01-04T23:51:04.184Z] Information: Reconnect attempt failed because of error 'WebSocket is not in the OPEN state'. Utils.ts:174:39
00:51:04.184 [2020-01-04T23:51:04.185Z] Information: Reconnect attempt number 2 will start in 2000 ms. Utils.ts:174:39
```

#### Here is hub method:

```
public async Task SendMessage(Message message)
{
    // Eager loading conversation with matching Id
    var chat = _context.Chat
        .Include(c => c.PersonA)
        .Include(c => c.PersonB)
        .FirstOrDefault(m => m.Id == message.ChatId);

    /*
     * I'm doing a few validations here
     */

    // Saving entity to the database
    await _context.AddAsync(new Message
    {
        SenderId = message.SenderId,
        ChatId = message.ChatId,
        Text = message.Text
    });
    await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

    // Dispatching message to the clients using strongly-typed hub
    var usersId = new List<string> { chat.PersonAId, chat.PersonBId };
    await Clients
        .Users(usersId)
        .ReceiveMessage(message);
}
```

The potential problem could lie in timing, the dispatching can't wait for the EF to execute all operations, because when I just load the conversation It works good, adding more complexity, it breaks down.

Comment: I would recommend using FirstOrDefaultAsync method (async version of FirstOrDefault) to retrieve the items, and Add method (non-async version) to add entity. That said, I don't think that's the error. It looks like something is throwing an exception which forcibly closes your hub connection. You only list the client side log, what does the server log say at the same time?